# jsf focus inputtext field after form rerenders with values onblur

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

After onbluring an input text field inside my form , I'm rerendering the form with the new values.

In this case the field loses it's focus, I want the input that was after the one I blured out from to be focused. is there an after render event, or somthing that will give the option to choose the cell i want to focus on?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Is it in your case really necessary to render the **entire** form instead of only the blurred input?

Comment: @BalusC:yes, beacuse i get all the fields values back from the server - i need to see them inside the form..

Comment: Show some code, so we could help with something.

Comment: I know this an old post, but I have found this post with an in depth explanation to the issue along with a workable solution approach: http://www.knitelius.com/2014/07/15/keeping-focus-on-element-with-jsf-2-ajax-render/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would work but you can try the following:

```
<h:form id="myForm">

   <h:inputText id="my1stInput" >
      <a4j:ajax event="blur" render="myForm" oncomplete="document.getElementById('myForm:my2ndInput').focus()" />
   </h:inputText>

   <h:inputText id="my2ndInput" />

</h:form>
```

Comment: i can't add the `oncomplete` inside my `a4j:ajax` tag - i get an error that this attribute is not supported. any other way? thank's!